# Importing Azure DevOps Work Item attachments to PBI

Tags: azure, powerbi, devops

I am currently working on a project that involves using Azure DevOps as the main management tool. However, our team has decided to analyze the data generated in the platform through Power BI reports. As such, there are some attachments in the work items that we would like to see displayed in PBI, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

- There are multiple ways to connect to the powerbi to devops and get the work item data. Such as by using analytical view, oData queries and oData feed, etc.
- To Create power bi reports using analytical view first you have to import data in the power bi, this can be done by selecting `azure devops` as an option in the `Online service` tab which itself is in the `get data` tab in the `powerbi destop app`

```
getdata -> online options -> azure devops
```

- After that it will ask you for organization and team and ask you to login to your devops account too.
- After this a popup will immerge and in which you can select the work items data based upon the duration time which has passed such today, last 30 days, entire history, etc.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Hello Hohit! Thanks for the reply!

I am familiar with the Power BI connection process. My question would be related to the possibility of importing attachments stored in work items located in Azure backlog. For example, suppose I would like to display an attached printscreen of a certain e-mail evidence related to a specific Azure work item in PBI, how could I do this?